# Etymology and meaning of the word "but" in the sentence

Tags: meaning, etymology

What the origin of *but* as it is used in following sentence?

> ...as if the waters had but newly retired from the face of the earth

Is it meaning is close to *yet* or *although* or it has independent meaning?

Comment: [Almost-identical question](/questions/8892) but while the answers explain the meaning they don't show the history. A good answer here would make this question the duplicate target.

Comment: I have searched Etymonline without success in the case of this particular usage, where it means something like 'only', where reason says it must be short for something like '<nothing> but' with the word 'nothing' understood.  Dictionaries like Cambridge English explain what it means, but without suggesting when or how it arose.  The Oxford English does suggest that this particular usage was first used in the 1930s, but I am not sure what the evidence is.  The Old English origin in the word 'butan' or 'buton' meaning 'except' is as far as I can get, apart from pure inference.

Comment: "But" means "only" here. The sense "Nothing but, no more than, only, merely" is late Old English according to the OED. My Old English isn't good enough to understand all the examples but they have "butan I gear & III monþas" (but one year and three months) c. 1000 and "buten lutel" (but little) c. 1200. The OED says this is somehow related to the use as a conjunction introducing an exception. It's impossible to exactly trace the evolution of meanings in Old English and especially between Old and Middle English due to the lack of written evidence but the OED is definitely the way to try it.

Comment: @Tuffy: 1930s? This from 1813 looks like the same usage as cited above: [*he had **but recently** begun to cultivate an acquaintance with the Greek theatre.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22had+but+recently+begun+to+cultivate+an+acquaintance%22)

Comment: @Tuffy The OP's quotation is from _[Bleak House](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleak_House)_ (1852), so the 1930's date must be wrong.  1830's, perhaps?

Comment: The etymology seems easy to guess intuitively. The basic meaning of "but" is "other than", but in this usage it means "slightly less than", which is a specific case. It's not common for words to develop either more general or more specific meanings.

Comment: @FumbleFingers&Tevildo - Thank you both for doing the research I had not done.

Comment: @Barmar: I think you're confusing ***just enough*** and ***just recently***. The cited usage has nothing to do with "slightly less than" - it's just ***only newly/recently...***

Answer (score 0):

*But* means ***just*** in Dickens’s sentence:

> *As much mud in the streets as if the waters had **just** newly retired from the face of the earth . . .*

The *OED* lists this sense as obsolete (obsolete now but still kicking around while Dickens was alive):

> **but** *preposition*, *adverb*, *conjunction*, & *noun<sup>2</sup>*
> **2.b.**† Neither more nor less than, absolutely, actually, just, even. Sometimes merely as a filler. *Obsolete* (*regional* in later
> use). **a1400–1844**
>  See also *but now*.
>  [↓]
> **P.4.** **but now**: just now, only this moment. Now *rare* **a1450–**
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login required)</sub>

Given the timeline and [Dickens’s affinity with all things Shakespearian](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41236557), the definition fits. Here are a couple of older usage samples of *but newly*:

> The dangers of the dayes but newly gone,
>  Whose memorie is written
> on the Earth
>  <sub>—Henry IV, [Mr. William Shakespear’s Comedies,
> Histories and
> Tragedies.](https://archive.org/details/bim_early-english-books-1641-1700_mr-william-shakespears_shakespeare-william_1685/page/n361/mode/2up?q=%22but+newly+gone%22)
> (William Shakespeare, 1685)</sub>
>
> But in the *Coffin* that had the *Bookes*, they were found as fresh,
> as if they had beene but newly Written, being written in *Parchment*,
> and covered over with *Watch-Candles* of *Wax*, three or foure
> fold.
>   <sub>—[*Sylua Syluarum: Or A Naturall Historie. In Ten
> Centuries.*](https://archive.org/details/baconsylvasylvarum/page/194/mode/2up?q=%22but+newly+written%22)
> (Francis Bacon, 1631)</sub>